# MySql Error no 1064

Tags: mysql

My table format is

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `clinicReg` (
  `clinicRegId` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `clinicName` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `clinicAddress` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `clinicContactNo` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `clinicContactNO1` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `clinicMobileNo` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `clinicMobileNo1` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `clinicCatagories` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `clinicServices` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `clinicLogo` longblob NOT NULL,
  `ownerName` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `clinicEmailId` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `clinicEmailId1` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `loginTimeStamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`clinicRegId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

my insert query is

```
insert into 'harshal.clinicreg' (clinicRegId,clinicName,
  clinicAddress,clinicContactNo,clinicContactNO1,
  clinicMobileNo,clinicMobileNo1,clinicCatagories,
  clinicServices,clinicLogo,ownerName,clinicEmailId,
  clinicEmailId1,loginTimeStamp)
Values
('ORCCli1','Smile Clinic','Mulund',
 3456,544,234,567,'Gen','ABC',
 load_file(C:\Users\harshal420\Pictures\Camera Roll\Capture.jpg),
 'Smile','abc@xyz.com','def@pqr.com', CURDATE());
```

It is giving me error 1064 can any one help me???

Comment: Please post the **complete** error message. You should **not** be storing images in a table.

Comment: "1064" is MySQLese for "SQL syntax error."

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because you have an error in your SQL syntax. More specifically it is because you have used the incorrect quoting character when quoting your database/table name; you should be using backticks (`) or no quotes when specifying a database name, table name or field name.

You also need to quote the path to your data using single or double quotes. See my example below.

```
insert into `harshal`.`clinicreg` (clinicRegId,clinicName,clinicAddress,clinicContactNo,clinicContactNO1,clinicMobileNo,clinicMobileNo1,clinicCatagories,clinicServices,clinicLogo,ownerName,clinicEmailId,clinicEmailId1,loginTimeStamp) Values ('ORCCli1','Smile Clinic','Mulund',3456,544,234,567,'Gen','ABC',load_file('C:\Users\harshal420\Pictures\Camera Roll\Capture.jpg'),'Smile','abc@xyz.com','def@pqr.com', CURDATE());
```

Comment: This is still invalid since MySQL look for `harshal.clinicreg` table instead of `clinicreg` table in `harshal` database.

Answer (score 0):

Your `INSERT` statement has two issues that I can see upfront:

```
insert into 'harshal.clinicreg'
```

You have to wrap the db/table name with backticks, not single-quotes:

```
insert into `harshal`.`clinicreg`
```

After this, the [`load_file()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file) function takes a string-input, but you're passing a literal. Try updating the full query to:

```
INSERT INTO `harshal`.`clinicreg`
    (clinicRegId,clinicName, clinicAddress,clinicContactNo,clinicContactNO1,clinicMobileNo,clinicMobileNo1,clinicCatagories,clinicServices,clinicLogo,ownerName,clinicEmailId, clinicEmailId1,loginTimeStamp)
VALUES
    ('ORCCli1','Smile Clinic','Mulund',  3456,544,234,567,'Gen','ABC',
     load_file('C:\\Users\\harshal420\\Pictures\\Camera Roll\\Capture.jpg'),
     'Smile','abc@xyz.com','def@pqr.com', CURDATE()
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 errors in your insert query.
1 - 
Your table name is wrong it should be

insert into clinicReg

you can also put dbname.clinicReg

2- in your query load_file(C:\Users\harshal420\Pictures\Camera Roll\Capture.jpg)
this gives error

Answer (score -1):

You probably want to do

```
insert into `harshal`.`clinicreg` (...)
```

instead of

```
insert into 'harshal.clinicreg' (...)
```

In your example MySQL gets a string instead of table identifier which is what it excepts here.

You can also miss backticks here at all.

There also second syntax error in your query. You should quote path string passed to `load_file` function as parameter. Should be:

```
load_file('C:\Users\harshal420\Pictures\Camera Roll\Capture.jpg') ,
```

Comment: This is still invalid. You need to either use backticks or no quoting.